# telerik:GridDropDownColumn not filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

" DataField="UserGroup_ID"
                                HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ListTextField="GroupName" AndCurrentFilterValue="GroupName" />

its filter by id but not in groupname ..why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

GridDropDownColumn Filter only knows about the data in your grid datasource e.g. your usegroupid. Therefore it can only filter on your dropdownlist "value" and not the text.

You would have to use a template column instead.